# Conditionally adding characters to new column based on separate dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hello all and thank you in advance.

I would like to add a new column to my pre-existing data frame where the values sourced from a second data frame based on certain conditions.  The dataset I wish to add the new column to ("data_melt") has many different sample IDs (sample.#) under the variable column.  Using a second dataset ("metadata") I want to add the pond names to the "data_melt" new column based on the sample-ids.  The sample IDs are the same in both datasets.

My gut tells me there's an obvious solution but my head is pretty fried.  Here is a toy example of my data_melt df (since its 25,000 observations):

```
> dput(toy)
structure(list(gene = c("serA", "mdh", "fdhB", "fdhA"), process = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "energy", class = "factor"), category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "metabolism", class = "factor"), ko = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K00058", 
"K00093", "K00125", "K00148"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72"
), class = "factor"), value = c(0.00116, 2.77e-05, 1.84e-05, 
0.0125)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is a toy example of my metadata df:

```
> dput(toy)
structure(list(sample = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72", 
"sample.13"), pond = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("lower", 
"upper"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match` from `base R` to create a numeric index to replace the values

```
toy$pond <- with(toy, out$pond[match(variable, out$sample)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe merge will work here.

```
sss <- structure(list(gene = c("serA", "mdh", "fdhB", "fdhA"), process = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "energy", class = "factor"), category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "metabolism", class = "factor"), ko = structure(1:4, .Label = c("K00058", 
"K00093", "K00125", "K00148"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72"
), class = "factor"), value = c(0.00116, 2.77e-05, 1.84e-05, 
0.0125)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

ss <- structure(list(sample = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72", 
"sample.13"), pond = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("lower", 
"upper"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

ssss <- merge(sss, ss, by.x = "variable", by.y = "sample")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join()` from the dplyr package after renaming `sample` to `variable` in the metadata data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_melt <- structure(list(gene = c("serA", "mdh", "fdhB", "fdhA"), 
                            process = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                                .Label = "energy", 
                                                class = "factor"), 
                            category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                                 .Label = "metabolism", 
                                                 class = "factor"), 
                            ko = structure(1:4, 
                                           .Label = c("K00058", "K00093", "K00125", "K00148"), 
                                           class = "factor"), 
                            variable = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
                                                 .Label = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72"), 
                                                 class = "factor"), 
                            value = c(0.00116, 2.77e-05, 1.84e-05, 0.0125)), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                       class = "data.frame")

metadata <- structure(list(sample = c("sample.10", "sample.19", "sample.72", "sample.13"), 
                           pond = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
                                            .Label = c("lower", "upper"), 
                                            class = "factor")), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                      class = "data.frame") %>%
  # Renaming the column, so we can join the two data sets together
  rename(variable = sample)

data_melt <- data_melt %>%
  left_join(metadata, by = "variable")
```